# How to use the -a option to pass a parameter to scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I read the doc and find the command line should be like this.
`scrapy runspider getspecificimg.py -a ip='lizhe'`

And my spider code is like this :

```
class GetImage(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ImageSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pexels.com/']

# Get the input argument
    # NameNeedSearch = InputPara
    NameNeedSearch = ip
```

But the result I get means that the `ip isn't defined why?`
[20161211162649.bmp](http://7xpvdr.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/20161211162649.bmp)

-- update --
I want to pass in a variable then use it to concatenate the `full url` and use it as the `start_url`
My code is like this :  and get the error `self is not defined` why is that ?

```
class GetImage(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ImageSpider'
# Get the input argument
    NameNeedSearch = self.ip
    # startUrl = 'https://www.pexels.com/' + 
    start_urls = ['https://www.pexels.com/']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your code using `self` in one of your `GetImage` class methods, for example `__init__` or `start_requests` that are called when starting the crawl.

When called by the framework, these methods will get as first argument the class instance itself, available as the conventional `self` variable used in the method signature (it's just a convention):

```
class GetImage(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'ImageSpider'
    start_urls = ['https://www.pexels.com/']

    def start_requests(self):
        # self points to the spider instance
        # that was initialized by the scrapy framework when starting a crawl
        #
        # spider instances are "augmented" with crawl arguments
        # available as instance attributes,
        # self.ip has the (string) value passed on the command line
        # with `-a ip=somevalue`
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url+self.ip, dont_filter=True)
```